# Why do I get different behaviors from the websites on the same machine and the same Internet?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, terminal

I'm trying to download some extensions from Microsoft's VS Code marketplace.

On the same machine:

1. Using Chrome, it downloads it, and it's fast
2. Using VS Code, it downloads it, but it's slow
3. Using `wget` from the terminal, I get 429 (Too Many Requests)

Why is it so? What do I miss about networking here?

Answer (score 1):

With `wget`, it's making stateless requests without any session information.  If you use a custom user agent it will, most likely, work.

```
ua="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
wget -U "$ua" "https://example.com/file.zip"
```

For credentials, here's how you use cookies:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies \
     --post-data 'username=yourusername&password=yourpassword' \
     http://example.com/login
```

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
     http://example.com/protected-page
```

Comment: I realized that the response body contains this message: `Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Count' in namespace 'AnonymousId'.` Maybe I should test your `--save-cookies`.